# How can i create a user with info about Display Name, username & Profile pic?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, firebase-authentication

How can i create a user with info about Display Name, username & Profile pic?

Can I use this code?

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
let name = user.displayName
let email = user.email
let photoUrl = user.photoURL
let uid = user.uid; // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
                    // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with
                    // your backend server, if you have one. Use
                    // getTokenWithCompletion:completion: instead.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

If not, for what purpose this code is used?
And which code can be used to determine username, profile pic etc,?

I'm new to firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provides authentication for users using the FIRAuth Clases/API

However they can't be edited with custom fields like the **Firebase Database**.

To allow custom fields for user, you need to duplicate users in the Database with the same unique `uid` you receive in the auth of the user. Something like this

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
  let name = user.displayName
  let email = user.email
  let photoUrl = user.photoURL
  let uid = user.uid; 

  let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
  let key = uid

        let userDict = [ "name"    : name ,
                         "email"   : email,
                     "photoUrl"    : photoUrl]

        let childUpdates = ["/users/\(key)": userDict]
        ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) -> Void in
              // now users exist in the database
        })
}
```

We push it at the `users` end point in our db and with the `uid` key by the following line `/users/\(key)`.

Comment: What's the work of the code below? After FIRDatabase?

Comment: It saves the user dict in our database at the specific end point `users/key`

Comment: Is that necessary ?

Comment: if you want the users to have custom fields - then you need to have users detail in your database too. This code shows how to do that.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much