# Retrieve User Data Firebase on Android

Tags: android, authentication, firebase

Is there a way to retrieve data from a specific user who is authenticated via firebase through ID?

For example to retrieve information like name, photo etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more of a port of the iOS answer i have given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37650499/1095089)

Firebase provides authentication for users using the FIRAuth Clases/API

However they can't be edited with custom fields like the **Firebase Database**.

To allow custom fields for user, you need to duplicate users in the Database with the same unique `uid` you receive in the auth of the user. Something like this

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
  // User is signed in
   String name = user.displayName;
   String email = user.email;
   String photoUrl = user.photoURL;
   String uid = user.uid;


    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    String key = database.getReference("users").push().getKey();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put( "uid", uid);
    childUpdates.put( "name", name);
    // other properties here

    database.getReference("users").updateChildren(childUpdates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError == null) {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

We push it at the `users` end point in our db and with the `uid` key by the following line `/users/\(key)`.

Now you can retrieve users detail from your database by querying anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks, this was my question, whether it was possible or not