# How to fetch particular data from Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase

I have integrated Google sign-in in my app and i am pushing some data in to fire base including user U-id.I had researched a lot and didn't get anything the problem i am facing that i want to fetch Particular data for eg If User A sign-in and push 5 data and Then User B sign-in and push 3 data.I want a query like if User A sing-in Again it will get his 5 data only and not the data which is pushed by User B.Thanks in Advance :)

By using this it fetch all the data from firebase:

```
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                FirebaseModel firebasemodel = 
      data.getValue(FirebaseModel.class);
                firebasemodels.add(firebasemodel);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I have tried all that .child .orderby and .equalTo but did'nt work

My Structure is Like:

[My FireBase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpVZv.png)

Comment: You can add this functionality by added a user_id and get data based on user_id

Comment: I am adding user id in firebase.the problem i am facing while fetching that user data

Comment: please check my answer hope will help you.

Comment: Check this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37827336/6021469

Answer (score 0):

You also need a reference to the data, which isn't included in your code block.  So something along the lines of (this should be before this):

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("notepad-secure/notepad");
```

Comment: I have added this line in Oncreate method

Answer (score 0):

To Fetch Particular values from the firebase,try this code

```
   FirebaseDatabase database;
   database.getReference().child("notepad-secure").orderByChild("id").equalTo(user).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    User userdet =childSnapshot.getValue(yourclass.class);
                    String note=userdet.note;
                   //Here you will get the string values what you want to fetch
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add a user_id key in your child data, it will look like below :

```
id:"",
note:"",
title:"",
user:""
user_id:"{id from which user have you uploaded data}"
```

And than you can call below function with specific user data like
       below Note : "user_id" = id from which user have you uploaded data

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query query = reference.child("notepad").orderByChild("id").equalTo("user_id");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            // dataSnapshot is the "notepad" node with all children with id 
            for (DataSnapshot notepad: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // do something with the individual "notepad_data" 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    } 
});
```

Comment: .equalTo("user_id"); in parameter shuold i add the user_id value ?

Comment: yes as i give you a example of child node.. Or if you can pass unique any value for particular user. May be your user key may be unique

Comment: What is you issue occur after adding the data have you print any log or anything, By that i can help you closely.

Comment: Have you add "user_id" key and value in you firebase database if yo add that key so can you please display your database screenshot

Comment: that "user" in my database is the key of user

Comment: What is you pass exactly in your function .have you debugged properly?

Comment: Replace "notepad" to "notepad-secure/notepad" and than try

Answer (score 0):

First U have to differentiate.U have to implement Firebase Authentication the u can get Firebase UID of every USER.

```
String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Then store seperatly in new node.
i.e Take Firebase Database Instance and

```
databaserefernace.child("Data").Child("userID);
```

Comment: Then retrieve The data

Answer (score 0):

When your add a user data to Firebase database, you can add it using the specific `uid` provided by the `FirebaseAuth` object like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Assuming you that your database strucure look like this: `Firebase root -> notepad-secure -> notepad`, to retrieve data, you can use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference notepadRef = rootRef.child("notepad-secure").child("notepad").child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String id = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);
        String note = dataSnapshot.child("note").getValue(String.class);
        String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
        String user = dataSnapshot.child("user").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", id + " / " + note + " / " + title + " / " + user);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
notepadRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```