# Firebase swift - Could not cast value of type 'FIRUserInfoImpl' to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a facebook and twitter login Button. I follow the [user guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_a_users_profile). I would like to store the user information however I receive this error `Could not cast value of type 'FIRUserInfoImpl' to 'NSDictionary'`

I am not sure why I cannot store the relevant data. Is that because the provider data did not match the object type?

```
func createFirebaseUser(){

        //MARK: Assign what to get from current User data.
        let key = ref.child("users").childByAutoId().key
        if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser{
        for profile in user.providerData {
        let userID = profile.uid as! String!
        let username = profile.displayName as! String!
        let email = profile.email as! String!
        let profilePicUrl = profile.photoURL as! NSURL!


        ref.child("users").updateChildValues(profile as? NSDictionary as! [NSObject : AnyObject])

        }
        }
```

Comment: A `profile` is of type `FIRUserInfo`, it cannot be casted to a dictionary. That's what the error message says. Maybe you have to create a dictionary from the extracted properties. And delete all exclamation marks in `String!` and `NSURL!`. You certainly want (and need) a non-optional.

Comment: Do you mean create a data model for it ?

Comment: Create something which matches the type of the parameter of `updateChildValues`

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649464/how-can-i-create-a-user-with-info-about-display-name-username-profile-pic/37650499#37650499

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dictionnary to send data with `updateChildValues`.